# Hibernate HQL - Use CASE WHEN in COUNT Statement like IF in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to port a MySQL Query that works to Hibernate HQL, this is all very new to me, so I am open to any kind of hint (Wrong Way, Wrong Structure, change all... ;) )

Two tables A and B. (Structure broken down, only the relevant parts)

A contains entrys, each with a unique ID.
B references those IDs and holds a boolean-like marker (TINYINT(1)).

I want to know how many rows there are in B for each row in A with the Id from A's Row and Marker == True (1).

My MySQL query was like this:

```
SELECT A.id, COUNT( IF( B.marker = 1, 1, NULL ) ) AS markerTrue, COUNT( IF( B.marker =0, 1, NULL ) ) AS markerFalse FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id GROUP BY A.id
```

It works and I ported it to this (HQL):

```
SELECT A.id, COUNT(CASE WHEN B.marker = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as markerTrue, COUNT(CASE WHEN B.marker = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as markerFalse FROM A LEFT JOIN B WITH B.a_id = A.id GROUP BY A.id
```

This throws an Exception:

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: CASE near ...

In the logs, there is also

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:19: unexpected token: CASE
>   antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: CASE

But thats just the same internal Error.

Is there a way to do this in HQL? Is there another *better* way, like restructuring the tables, what is an experts opinion on this?

Answer (score 9):

I am by no means an expert — when HQL stymies me, I rarely have qualms about bypassing the problem by switching to straight SQL — so I can't tell you if there is a better, more HQL-ish way to do this. But in your specific instance, where `B.marker` is always either `0` or `1`, I suppose you *could* change

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN B.marker = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

to

```
SUM(B.marker)
```

and

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN B.marker = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

to

```
COUNT(*) - SUM(B.marker)
```

(though you *may* also need to wrap your `SUM`s in `COALESCE(..., 0)` — I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite in SQL. I hope it's more easily converted to HQL:

```
SELECT A.id
     , COALESCE(markerTrue, 0) AS markerTrue
     , COALESCE(markerFalse, 0) AS markerFalse 
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT a_id
           , COUNT(*) AS markerTrue
      FROM B 
      WHERE marker = 1
      GROUP BY a_id
    ) AS BT
    ON BT.a_id = A.id
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT a_id
           , COUNT(*) AS markerFalse
      FROM B 
      WHERE marker = 0
      GROUP BY a_id
    ) AS BF
    ON BF.a_id = A.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Oops, maybe too late?
Try :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN B.marker = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS your_result
```

as there is no "conditionnal" count...